# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'signature' --TensorFlow1.15 and Python2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tensorflow

I have a code that is written for Python 3. Due to certain limitations, I have to run this using Python 2. We were able to fix the majority of errors but I am not sure how to make the following lines compatible with Python 2 and tensorflow 1.15.

```
model = load_model(
    "../../deepposekit-data/datasets/fly/best_model_densenet.h5",
    augmenter=augmenter,
    generator=data_generator,
)
```

The error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-f6163a04b262> in <module>()
      2     "../../deepposekit-data/datasets/fly/best_model_densenet.h5",
      3     augmenter=augmenter,
----> 4     generator=data_generator,
      5 )

/projectnb/dnn-motion/jalal/.conda/envs/deepposekit/lib/python2.7/site-packages/deepposekit/models/loading.pyc in load_model(path, generator, augmenter, custom_objects)
     94 
     95     if generator:
---> 96         signature = inspect.signature(TrainingGenerator.__init__)
     97         keys = [key for key in signature.parameters.keys()]
     98         keys.remove("self")

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'signature'
```

Comment: Doesn't look like deepposekit ever support python 2 apart from in a couple of dev builds

Comment: yeah but we got to get majority of it working including the training. I can see that in this Website https://github.com/NiklasRosenstein/pydoc-markdown/issues/21 a hack is proposed. However, I am not exactly sure how to apply it to this code: https://pastebin.com/NLxDKdAZ

Comment: Why are you unable to use python 3?

Comment: there is a situation with our server setup that will be fixed next week. This week I have to make it work with Python2. I have a conference deadline on December 15th